# Logical paradox - custom function - parameters are coming from another fucntion

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, global-variables

I hope I can make this makes sense....

I have gone through a bunch of other functions to end up with a variable that contains the data selected by a user from a drop down list on a sidebar to my google sheet.

The final function that that variable is sent to is like this:

```
function processFormResponse(formObject ){

  reportMonth = formObject.chosenReport;

  //result of reportMonth is a string. Example "Report_Nov 2017"
}
```

So now I have a variable called reportMonth that has what I need. But now, I want to write a vlookup that will select the same range every time but on a different sheet depending on the user selection (reportMonth).
From what I have researched, I cant use variable inside the vlookup, so I was going to write a custom function that does the lookup for me.

But here's my paradox: I cant use processFormResponse as my custom function because it has the formObject already inside its parameters because its already receiving information from the previous function and I cant do a separate function because I can't seem to get reportMonth to be global... (I with and without var)

I basically something like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3, reportMonth !$F:$J,2,false),"")
```

Comment: In Google Sheets lingo, "custom function" has an special meaning. Is your question about an *user defined worksheet function* to be used in a formula? Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As mentioned in the Google Apps script documentation:

For the `Range` object:

```
setValue(value)
```

Sets the value of the range. The value can be numeric, string, boolean or date. **If it begins with '=' it is interpreted as a formula.**

So, if you have a 1-cell `Range` (a.k.a. a block of cells), then you could run

```
range.setValue("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,"+reportMonth+"!$F:$J,2,false),"")");
```

---

For Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue

Comment: Did you mean the range.Setvalue to be my new custom function?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Im getting there... I went back to basics and did a simpler function, now Im getting a grasp on this and I think I will get t eventually!